# How to add set of classes to OMNet++?

Tags: omnet++

I have a package for solving linear programming problems called SoPlex that I want to use in an OMNet++ project. There is only a source folder for the package that contains `.h` and `.cpp` files of implementation of package. I thought that I need to make a library out of those source and header files. Therefore, I used Code::Blocks to make a dynamic library of the package.

In OMNet++, I went to `Project Features` --> `Makemake` --> `Link` --> `Additional librariers to link with`

In that path, I entered the name of library `soplexlib`. I also added the path to both library files `libsoplexlib.a` and `soplexlib.dll` in `Paths and Symbols` section. 
Now when I build the project it says it cannot find there is no such file as `soplex.h`, while there is such file in source folder of soplex package. And I have added the path to that source and header files in `Includes` subsection of `Paths and Symbols` section in properties for my project.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OMNeT++` project probably uses Makefile, therefore changing `Paths and Symbols` in IDE will not resolve your problem.
 
You should go to `Project` | `Properties` | `OMNeT++` | `Makemeke` | select root or `src` directory | `Options`, then `Custom` | `Makefrag` and write the following lines:

```
EXTRA_OBJS += -LD:/foo/lib
CFLAGS += -ID:/foo/src
```

where `D:/foo/lib` is a directory which contains `libsoplexlib.a`, and  `D:/foo/src` - `soplex.h`.

Or, you can remove previously added libraries in `Link` option, and write in `Makefrag`:

```
EXTRA_OBJS += -LD:/foo/lib -lsoplexlib
CFLAGS += -ID:/foo/src
```

Moreover, I suggest turning on verbose mode for compiler. To do that go to `C/C++ Build`, uncheck `Use default build command` and write at the end of the command: `V=1`.

Answer (score 0):

An other approach is to rename the .cpp files to .cc and copy all of the files into your source directory. Regenerate the makefile (if you are using IDE, that's done automatically) and you are set. The makefile generator automatically picks up all .cc files in your source folder.

Comment: You mean I change all .cpp files in soplex package into .cc and copy all the .cc files including .h files of soplex package to the source directory of my omnet project?

Comment: I think this is no suitable option.. Linking as library seems more straight forward.

Comment: What approach you follow is really depending on how big the given 3rd part component is. If you have only a few .cc files, it may be much easier to just throw them inside the project (of course the include path for the compiler still has to be set so the include files will be accessible for the .cc files). For bigger projects, the library approach may be more effective (as you don't have to rebuild the 3rd party component each time you rebuild your project).